# forward all subdomains to an ip in bind

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a bind DNS server and i'd like to catch all requests for subdomains that don't have a specific record and point them to a specific IP.

This would be like *.domain.tld > 1.1.1.1 and www.domain.tld > 2.2.2.2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just adding the wildcard entry should work.

```
www.domain.tld. 14400 IN A 2.2.2.2
*.domain.tld. 14400 IN A 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Does the wildcard also include the main domain?

Comment: @ram4nd No, it only covers the subdomains. Ref https://serverfault.com/questions/473284/wildcard-dns-redirect-to-root-as-well

Comment: Just to add that you can use a `CNAME` record to the canonical name instead to the ip e.g `@ -> 1.1.1.1` `* -> CNAME domain.tld.` and `www -> 2.2.2.2`